# Fetch contents from a unicode URL

Tags: php

I would like to fetch the contents (HTML) from this URL: `http://www.tvsporedi.si/spored.php?id=Vaš kanal`. I've tried with File_Get_Contents and cURL.

No matter how I construct the URL in my code the page always returns a blank page (a page with header&menu but no content). I tried url encoding the id parameter, leaving the id as it is, without any luck. The only change I can make to the url (it seems) is encoding the space (with `%20`. Encoding the `š` does not work.

So I guess what I'm asking is why does PHP "eat" the `š`? The PHP file is saved with UTF-8 encoding ...

Comment: @Gordon wired, I get a table with some data in it, try clicking on some link in the navigation menu to see an example of what you should be seeing.

Comment: FYI, you can request to merge your accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Comment: Cheers Rob! Didn't know that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try fetching:

http://www.tvsporedi.si/spored.php?id=Va%C5%A1%20kanal

This works for me in a browser, and I would guess with whatever method you use.

I used Firebug to see how the browser was encoding the request...

Comment: Huh, that's f*** strange, it works now, but it didn't before ... well anyhow thanks :) I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

works for me with `urlencode`:

```
readfile('http://www.tvsporedi.si/spored.php?id=' . urlencode('Vaš kanal'));
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wKWj7b)